# Reference request for problem books on probability

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Can someone suggest some good books which contain Olympiad level questions and many solved examples on probability theory and combinatorics?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have already checked out the Art of Problem Solving competition preparation books (Volume 2, Intermediate Counting and Probability etc.). If not I recommend you take a look at those.

When I first started studying Probability Theory, I used Introduction to Mathematical Statistics by Hogg and Craig. Its rigorous and assumes the student has some Multi-Variable Calculus as well as undergraduate mathematical maturity.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried [Schaum's Study Guides](https://www.mhprofessional.com/test-prep-study-guides/schaum-s-study-guides-series)?
2. I recommend [*One Thousand Exercises in Probability* (2020 3 edn.)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/one-thousand-exercises-in-probability-9780198847618?cc=ca&lang=en&) by Geoffrey Grimmett and David Stirzaker.

> - It includes worked solutions to all exercises and problems in the associated textbook. This is an invaluable handbook for students and teachers attending or giving courses in probability

> - It contains more than 1300 [approximately 1317] exercises across a range of difficulty and topic. It is an essential aid for teachers compiling examinations and seeking exercises to illuminate lecture courses.